# Stop on-screen keyboard from automatic popup

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad, on-screen-keyboard

How can I stop the pop-up keyboard from automatically popping up anytime I click on a place to type?  I really do use the regular keyboard most often. This is on a Lenovo Yoga Thinkpad running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I turn off the virtual keyboard on a Yoga Pro 2 laptop?

> We're going to make it so that the On-Screen Keyboard will NOT pop
>   into view without your permission, but still have the On-Screen
>   Keyboard available to you when you use tablet mode.
>
> 1. Go to the Charm search (Win + C)
> 2. Type in "On-Screen Keyboard" An On-Screen Keyboard will appear, but it will look different than the one you're used to. This one has a
>      Win7 style minimize button.
> 3. Click that minimize button! The new-style On-Screen Keyboard will minimize to the Taskbar on your Desktop, out of your way.
>
> Now, DON'T TOUCH IT! Just leave it open & minimized in the Taskbar.
>
> As long as that new keyboard sits minimized in the Taskbar, when you
>   touch or click on any text box in any context the OS will think that
>   the On-Screen Keyboard is already enabled, except it won't shove it
>   back in front of your face, it will stay neatly minimized. You won't
>   see it.
>
> Meanwhile, the hardware keyboard on your Yoga will continue to work
>   like normal. Success!
>
> When you want to use the computer in regular tablet mode again, just
>   switch back your Desktop (Win + D) and close the On-Screen Keyboard
>   like you would any regular Desktop app.
>
> So now, when you flip your Yoga back to tablet mode, you'll still have
>   regular access to that On-Screen Keyboard when you need it, in its
>   intended context.
>
> (You'll still have to reengage that alternate On-Screen Keyboard each
>   time you come back to laptop mode from tablet mode, but it only takes
>   a second to do so. ....I did say this was a workaround, not a fix.)

Source [Turn off virtual keyboard in laptop mode of Yoga Pro 2](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Yoga-Flex-Laptops-and/Turn-off-virtual-keyboard-in-laptop-mode-of-Yoga-Pro-2/td-p/1504860)